# Trouble implementing North-East Paths with recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm supposed to use recursion to output the total number of unique north-east paths ne(x, y) to get from point A to point B, where B is x rows north and y columns east of A. In addition, I am required to print the possible unique NE paths.

I know how to use recursion to get the total number of unique paths. However, I am stuck with using recursion to print all the NE paths correctly.

This is the given output of some test cases:
[image of output](https://codecrunch.comp.nus.edu.sg/taskfile.php/846/output.png)

[image: my faulty recursive code]

Anyway, here's a screenshot of my faulty recursive code.
Please do give me advice where I went wrong. I have been burning a lot of time on this, but still I can't reach a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think you should print if( rows == 0 && cols == 0 ), because it's the case when you've reached point B.
2. Why are you using path+="N" in the first ne call in return? this will add "N" to original path and then you'll get path+"N"+"E" in the second call.

Try following:

```java
public static int ne( int rows, int cols, String path )
{
   if( rows == 0 && cols == 0 )
   {
      System.out.println(path);
      return 1;
   }
   int npats = 0, wpaths = 0;
   if( rows != 0 )
      npaths = ne( rows-1, cols, path+"N" );
   if( cols != 0 )
      wpaths = ne( rows, cols-1, path+"E" );
   return npaths + wpaths;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But I can't understand the code fully. Why do we have to break the code into two cases : if(rows != 0) and if(cols!=0) ?

Comment: if rows == 0 call with rows-1 will be unnecessary (and incorrect, what means rows=-1 ??) - we've already reached on of the target coordinates, and now we have to only move in other direction